# The TB Mega Menu Responsive Menu Icon Not Working Correctly

Tags: routes, blocks, navigation

For some reason the responsive menu icon is showing at the bottom and to the left of the menu bar on mobile devices. Specifically on iPads. On Andriod devices the menu icon doesn't even show where it should be. I inspected the elements and noticed that the placement section where the icon menu supposed to go (tb-special-menu) is set to display none:

[image]

Not sure if that's the issue. When I set it to tb-mega-menu it works but it replaces the design of the full site as well.

Example of it not working: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//thepoliticus.com/content/why-bernie-sanders-was-right-ignore-question-religion&w=768&h=1024&a=22

Example of how it should look: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//demo.themebrain.com/%23magz&w=768&h=1024&a=22

Comment: Looks like you need to adjust your breakpoints b/c it's not showing on anything smaller than an iPad for me.

Comment: And you need to make sure that the correct float is set on the menu, if you look at the screen width at around 968px (height doesn't matter much) you will see that the menu is all in one line but the menu is to the right of the logo and not in its correct place. This means you have either placed it in the wrong order or the floats are not right for the correct screen sizes.